# How do I write a fraction in android studio

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-studio, textview

How to do I write a fraction in android studio. What's the best practice for a fraction with a horizontal line I am trying to produce.

Comment: hey, see my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Use html format. However you must add a extra space on the top and bottom to keep it from being cut off.

```
 SpannableStringBuilder test = new SpannableStringBuilder();
 test.append("\n");
 test.append(Html.fromHtml("<sup>5</sup>/<sub>9</sub>"));
 test.append("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution does not seem simple, however if you want to try fraction in xml, go to this website.

http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=fraction

This code worked for me to show <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub>.

The xml code is.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="\u00BC"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
```

The required line is `android:text="\u00BC"` to show <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> as fraction.

**So if you want to show <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> or any other as fraction from the above mentioned website, just append the last two characters(in this case `BD`)  to `\u00`.**

**So 1/2 becomes \u00BD**

Comment: Well what if I'm trying to do other equations like the quadrant equation how would that be written in xml

Comment: Just checkout see the link which i have given in the answer, it probably has all the fractions  :-)

Comment: But what about custom formula with exponents etc

Comment: i think it is given in the link, checkout the link

Comment: Not sure if I missed it but all I see is numbers with the / when I'm looking for a horizontal line

Comment: See Mou's answer, i think that suites your requirement

Comment: I guess I kinda overlooked it. I suppose it can work

Comment: if this answer has helped you by some amount, kindly consider upvoting it

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/11/android-stacked-fractions.html

Basically, you have to looking for a font that supports afrc. Now, you can play with your TextViews and TagHandlers until you get the result desired.

Comment: Well what if I'm trying to do other equations like the quadrant equation how would that be written in xml

Comment: You can use HTML for that

Comment: Well I can't seem to figure out how to do some like the quadratic equation. I don't want a ” / " either I want a straight horizontal line which I seem to not be able to get